# Of 30 chestnuts, 7 have worms: what is the probability of drawing the first 20 all worm-free?

Tags: probability

There are 30 chestnuts in a bag of which 7 have worms, what is the probability of drawing the first 20 all free from worms?
I thought of the problem as either drawing a good or bad chestnut. My answer is

$$\frac{23 \choose 20}{30 \choose 20} $$, I found that this is equivalent to
$$ \frac{23*22*21*20*...*(23-(20-1))}{30*29*28*27*...*(30-(20-1))}$$
Is is correct?

Mathematica commands: 
$$ \frac{FactorialPower[23, 20]}{FactorialPower[30, 20]}==\frac{Binomial[23, 20]}{Binomial[30, 20]}==\frac{1}{16965}$$

Comment: I HATE probability and/or combinatorics,so excuse me if I don't leap to answer that one..........lol

Comment: Don't blame you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, except that you need parentheses around $23-(20-1)$ in the numerator and $30-(20-1)$ in the denominator; better yet, replace them by $4$ and $11$, respectively. And if you want to evaluate it by hand, you instead expand the first fraction like this

$$\frac{\binom{23}{20}}{\binom{30}{20}}=\frac{\frac{23!}{20!3!}}{\frac{30!}{20!10!}}=\frac{23!10!}{3!30!}=\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4}{30\cdot29\cdot28\cdot27\cdot26\cdot25\cdot24}$$

and cancel to reduce it to

$$\frac1{3\cdot29\cdot3\cdot13\cdot5}=\frac1{16965}\;.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm never really sure that I approach these questions properly.

Comment: @John: You’re very welcome.